# parameter of std::normal_distribution constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the parameter `sigma` of `std::normal_distribution`'s constructor squared or not?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sigma` parameter is the standard deviation and not the variance. For instance, the code below outputs `4` (and not `2`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main() {
    std::normal_distribution<double> d(0.0, 4.0);
    std::cout << d.stddev() << std::endl;
}
```